# Cannot run a database restore on Powershell because of < character

Tags: mysql, powershell, command-line, backup, restore

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
&$parameterHash["mysql"] -u $parameterHash["user"] -p"$($parameterHash['password'])" -h $parameterHash["host"] $parameterHash['database'] `< $parameterHash['backup-path']
```

Pay attention to this part of the whole command:

```
$parameterHash['database'] `< $parameterHash['backup-path']
```

This is the syntax of `mysql` command-line to restore a backup (i.e. *a SQL script*) from a file system location to a given database by its name.

First of all, I had to escape `>` in Powershell with a backtick.

The issue is that the entire command isn't recognized by `mysql` command line when I run it from Powershell. Once I run it, `mysql` outputs the help.

If I output the command as a string and I try to run it in regular `CMD` (i.e. `cmd.exe`) it works as expected.

For now, I can't figure out what's going on.

### Update

I've also tried this:

```
$restoreArgs = "-u $($parameterHash["user"]) -p""$($parameterHash['password'])"" -h $($parameterHash["host"]) $($parameterHash['database']) < $($parameterHash['backup-path'])"
Start-Process $parameterHash["mysql"] $restoreArgs
```

...and I got the same result.

Comment: `Start-Process $parameterHash['mysql'] "-u $($parameterHash["user"]) -p""$($parameterHash['password')"" -h $($parameterHash["host"]) $($parameterHash['database'])" -RedirectStandardInput $parameterHash['backup-path'] -NoNewWindow -Wait`

Comment: @PetSerAl It could be another option! For now, it seems that the most elegant solution is the piping approach with `Get-Content -Raw`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't support input redirection, only [output redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx). I don't have MySQL at hand right now, so I can't test, but you could try

```
Get-Content $parameterHash['backup-path'] | &$parameterHash["mysql"] -u $parameterHash["user"] -p"$($parameterHash['password'])" -h $parameterHash["host"] $parameterHash['database']
```

If the input must be a single string call `Get-Content` with the parameter `-Raw` (PowerShell v3 and newer):

```
Get-Content $parameterHash['backup-path'] -Raw | ...
```

or pipe the `Get-Content` output through `Out-String` first:

```
Get-Content $parameterHash['backup-path'] | Out-String | ...
```

Another option is to run the commandline with CMD, which does support [input redirection](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true):

```
$mysql  = $parameterHash["mysql"]
$user   = $parameterHash["user"]
$pass   = $parameterHash['password']
$server = $parameterHash["host"]
$db     = $parameterHash['database']
$backup = $parameterHash['backup-path']

cmd /c "$mysql -u $username -p $password -h $server -d $db < $backup"
```

Comment: Piping `Get-Content` worked like a charm! Thank you for the effort to explain what was wrong ;)